# getNumber doesn't exist in CommandInteractionOptionResolver discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a simple add slash command with discord.js, but it seems that `interaction.options.getNumber` just doesn't exist (look at https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/src/structures/CommandInteractionOptionResolver.js#L181)

This is a piece of my code:

```
...
    commands?.create({
        name: 'add',
        description: 'add two numbers',
        options: [
        {
            name: 'num1',
            description: 'The first num',
            required: true,
            type: DiscordJS.ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number
        },
        {
            name: 'num2',
            description: 'The second num',
            required: true,
            type: DiscordJS.ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number
        }  ]    
    })

})
... 
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) {
        return
    }
    const { commandName, options } = interaction

    if (commandName === 'add') {
        console.log(options)
        const num1 = options.getNumber('num1')!
        const num2 = options.get('num2')!
        // idk why but "get" method exists. So I was trying to use it,
        // but js says that you couldn't add a string | number | boolean value to an another one 
        console.log(num1.value + num2.value)
        console.log(typeof(num2.value)) // this prints "number" btw
        
        interaction.reply({ 
            content: `The sum is ${num1.value}`
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, but it's intricate:

```
...
    } else if (commandName === 'add') {
        console.log(options)
        const raw_num1 = options.get('num1')!
        const raw_num2 = options.get('num2')!
        const num1 = raw_num1.value!
        const num2 = raw_num2.value!

        
        interaction.reply({ 
            content: `The sum is ${+(num1) + +(num2)}`
        })
    }
})
```